# using time command in bash script and redirect the output

Tags: bash, redirect, time

I'm trying to write a script that does

```
x =$ncore
numactrl -C $x ( time -p $exe ) > out.txt 2>&1
```

on the terminal ( time $ exe ) > out.txt 2>&1 worked as i wanted to (out.txt containing output of time and executable )

i'm using red hat 6.2 and time is not GNU version( i'm assuming from the fact that -a -o options don't work)

i want out.txt to have output from the executable and at the end have output from the time command.

the bash script is giving me problems with having ( so i used ( time -p $exe ) and now numactl sees ( as the executable.

is there a way to use numactl and time command together and have the output i want ?

Answer (score 2):

If `numactrl` wants a command, but you want to use some shell features, just give it the shell as a command:

```
numactrl -C $x bash -c "( time -p $exe ) > out.txt 2>&1"
```

When you run`time -p $exe` from a bash prompt or within a `bash -c`, you're using the bash builtin version of time. The one with the `-o` option is an external command, so to use it from bash you have to specify `command time` or `/bin/time` or `/usr/bin/time`.

If you run `numactrl -C $x time ...` then it probably runs the external command, so `-o` should work in that case, but if not then you always have the `bash -c` method.

Note that the output format is different between the various versions of `time`. The GNU coreutils version prints more information than the bash builtin version.